# add custom numbers to ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm drawing a `geom_tile` plot where i have each point with a specific `p-value`.

The plot is drawn in a nice way with the `p-value` limits on the legend.

What i want to add to this legend is the number of data points which have this `p-value`.

Example:

the legend is something like that (with a color for each value):

```
0.05
0.04
0.03
0.02
0.01
```

what i want to have is something like this:

```
0.05 58
0.04 34
0.03 85
0.02 54
0.01 10
```

how can i add this to the legend of `ggplot2` plots?

I tried using geom_text and change the text position to the legend, but it did not worked.

***UPDATE***

```
pl <- ggplot(df.new) + geom_tile(aes(fill=z, x, y)) + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red", name="Legend1") + 
      stat_contour(breaks=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), aes(x=x, y=y, z=npvalue, colour=..level..)) +
      scale_colour_gradient2(low="black", mid="black", high="green", labels=paste(levels(c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05))))
```

I have this plot, I'm drawing the `geom_tile` correctly from the `z` variable then im drawing a `stat_contour` based on the p-value. And i want to edit the labels for the `stat_contour` colors which are based on the `p-value` as in my initial question, but i'm having this error :

```
Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, breaks) : 
  Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

Where is the problem in my plotting??

Comment: People are generally much more happy to help if you provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and show the code you have tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the `labels` of the legend for the `fill` colours.

An example dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5), y = rep(1:10), 
                  z = factor(sample(seq(0.01, 0.05, 0.01), 100, TRUE)))
```

The function `table` counts the different values of `dat$z`:

```
table(dat$z)

# 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 
#   13   25   19   26   17
```

The plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = paste(levels(dat$z), table(dat$z)))
```

In the last line, the `labels` of the legend are created.

[image]

Comment: thank you for you comment, this works, but i have a short update to the question which made things a bit more complicated for me and i'm getting an error. please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @ifreak Is your z variable not discrete but continuous?

Comment: the z variable is continuous, its basically the p-value but it has a lot of values other than the breaks, but what i want is to only draw the count for the values that are within the break

Comment: @ifreak You can create cuts using `tmp <- cut(dat$z, seq(0, .5, .1))`. Then you can use this for your plot: `scale_fill_gradient(breaks = seq(0, .5, .1), labels = paste(levels(tmp), table(tmp)))`.