# Label minimum and maximum of scale fill gradient legend with text: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend, fill

I have a plot created in `ggplot2` that uses `scale_fill_gradientn`. I'd like to add text at the minimum and maximum of the scale legend. For example, at the legend minimum display "Minimum" and at the legend maximum display "Maximum". There are posts using discrete fills and adding labels with numbers instead of text (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808881/add-custom-numbers-to-ggplot-legend)), but I am unsure how to use the `labels` feature with `scale_fill_gradientn` to only insert text at the min and max.  At the present I am apt to getting errors:

```
Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, breaks) : 
Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

Is this text label possible within ggplot2 for this type of scale / fill?

```
# The example code here produces an plot for illustrative purposes only.
# create data frame, from ggplot2 documentation
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5) 
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(7),na.value = "transparent")
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531865/colorbar-guide-with-string-labels/59532260#59532260

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For `scale_fill_gradientn()` you should provide both arguments: `breaks=` and `labels=` with the same length. With argument `limits=` you extend colorbar to minimum and maximum value you need.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + 
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(7),na.value = "transparent",
                           breaks=c(0,0.5,1),labels=c("Minimum",0.5,"Maximum"),
                           limits=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I am using the following command to no avail. The min and max values do not show on the color bar. Here is my code
`scale_fill_gradientn(colours=pal(100), breaks=breaks,
                       limits=lim,
                       labels=breaks,
                       guide = guide_colorbar(title=expression(paste('hr', sep="")), title.position = "right", 
                                              title.vjust = 0.8, barwidth = 75))`

Comment: Code is still valid. Your code can't be checked as it is not reproducible.

Comment: @Gandalf, there must have been a breaking change sometime. `limits` used to transform the scale now its a hard critereon and every value outside will become the NA-Color. Try it out with `df$z <- runif(nrow(df)) * 9`.

Comment: The problem with NA values and limits can be dealt with using a bit more automatism...  For one suggestion how to - [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698823/7941188)

Answer (score 6):

[User Didzis Elfert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265801/7941188) slightly lacks "automatism" in my opinion (but it is of course pointing to the core of the problem +1 :).
Here an option to programatically define minimum and maximum of your data.

Advantages:

- You will not need to hard code values any more (which is error prone)
- You will not need hard code the limits (which also is error prone)
- Passing a named vector: You don't need the labels argument (manually map labels to values is *also* error-prone).
- As a side effect you will avoid the "non-matching labels/breaks" problem

```r
library(ggplot2)
foo <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
foo$z <- runif(nrow(foo))

myfuns <- list(Minimum = min, Mean = mean, Maximum = max)

ls_val <- unlist(lapply(myfuns, function(f) f(foo$z)))

# you only need to set the breaks argument! 
ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = topo.colors(7),
    breaks = ls_val
  )
```

[image]

```r
# You can obviously also replace the middle value with sth else

ls_val[2] <- 0.5
names(ls_val)[2] <- 0.5

ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = topo.colors(7),
    breaks = ls_val
  )
```

[image]